# How do i turn this day by day image code to change image by day but at a fixed time not midnight

Tags: javascript, html, image, time

so here is the code i have got

```
var imlocation = "../assets/oldham/";
function ImageArray (n) {
this.length = n;
for (var i =1; i <= n; i++) {
 this[i] = ' '
  }
 }
image = new ImageArray(7);
image[0] = 'sunday.jpg';
image[1] = 'monday.jpg';
image[2] = 'tuesday.jpg';
image[3] = 'wednesday.jpg';
image[4] = 'thursday.jpg';`enter code here`
image[5] = 'friday.png';
image[6] = 'saturday.png';
var currentdate = new Date();
var imagenumber = currentdate.getDay();
document.write('<img src="' + imlocation + image[imagenumber] + '">');`
```

At current it will change the photo on the stroke of 12 midnight but as its a late night bar i want it to change at 6am how would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will take into account the hour of the day, if it's before 6am, the code will show the image from the previous day.

```
var imlocation = "../assets/oldham/";
function ImageArray (n) {
this.length = n;
for (var i =1; i <= n; i++) {
 this[i] = ' '
  }
 }
image = new ImageArray(7);
image[0] = 'sunday.jpg';
image[1] = 'monday.jpg';
image[2] = 'tuesday.jpg';
image[3] = 'wednesday.jpg';
image[4] = 'thursday.jpg';`enter code here`
image[5] = 'friday.png';
image[6] = 'saturday.png';
var currentdate = new Date();
var imagenumber = currentdate.getDay();
var hour = currentdate.getHours();

if (hour < 6) {
  imagenumber = imagenumber - 1;

  if (imagenumber == -1) imagenumber = 6;
}

document.write('<img src="' + imlocation + image[imagenumber] + '">');`
```